# CakePHP syntax error

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this line of code, unfortunately though it has a syntax error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW on line 1

Here is the code:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('View/Edit', array('action' => 'view', $client['Client']['id']), "?" => array('nc' => time(), array('class' => 'view')); ?>
```

Where is the mistake in here and how can I get this resolved?

Comment: what link you want to make by this

Comment: you missed round bracket at the end

Comment: Suresh Kamrushi: I want to append ?nc=xxx (where xxx stays for the php timestamp to the url.  @Akam : I've tried to add an additional round bracket after 'view')) however the error still persists.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with cakePHP, but maybe the round bracket after ['Client']['id'] should not be there?

Comment: Try to work to a sensible margin, even in your view layer - it will make mistakes like this much easier to detect. See @dev-null-dweller's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use indentation and this will be clear:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->link(
    'View/Edit', 
    array(
        'action' => 'view', 
         $client['Client']['id']
     ), 
    "?" => array(
        'nc' => time(), 
        array(
           'class' => 'view'
        )
    ); 
?>
```

As you can see, you have closed an array after `$client['Client']['id']`, so `"?" =>` is treated as parameter to `link` function and causing an error.

Comment: +1 brownie points for giving a *proper* answer and not simply 'add this: )'